# Radio Buttons in React-Materialize or even Materialize-css inside modal doesn't work

Tags: forms, reactjs, radio-button, materialize

So it seems its not even inside of the modal but simply the Radio Buttons onChange doesn't work properly. The clicking/onChange will get registered once, and not even on the first click (it takes the second click like the button needs a click to be prepped) and then after that the buttons LOOK like they work fine but the onClick never get registered again. Just once and thats it

I followed [this](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/forms) documentation exactly and have been using the same form submission methods for all my forms/onChange buttons

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, and noticed that the last patch they made to fix Radios in fact broke this behavior. Reverting to the last previous version resolves the issue. Not quite a fix, but until then, it will get you working again.

It looks like this issue (which is marked closed) is the culprit. https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues/422

Comment: That's good looking out! I ended up with a hacky work around but I like it so far. I'll post it as an answer as well in case anyone is wondering how to use RadioButtons with a lil materialize in there

Answer (score 0):

So my solution took basically making `radio buttons` the react way and adding a small bit of materialize for the buttons. just keep the `name` attribute the same for all the values and going to the right `this.state`

```
<Row onClick={this.handleChange} >
  <Col s={12}>
    <Col s={4} style={{marginTop: '80px'}}>
        <Col s={12}>
          <Col s={3} className='center'><Button type="button" value="endangered" name="cause" floating={true} className={(this.state.cause === 'endangered') ? 'green' : 'blue'} style={radioStyle}/></Col>
          <Col s={9}><label>Endagered Animals & Wildlife</label></Col>
        </Col>
        <Col s={12}>
            <Col s={3} className='center'><Button type="button" value="microplastics" name="cause" floating={true} className={(this.state.cause === 'microplastics') ? 'green' : 'blue'} style={radioStyle}/></Col>
            <Col s={9}><label>Microplastics & Ocean Pollution</label></Col>
        </Col>
        <Col s={12}>
            <Col s={3} className='center'><Button type="button" value="carbon" name="cause" floating={true} className={(this.state.cause === 'carbon') ? 'green' : 'blue'} style={radioStyle}/></Col>
            <Col s={9}><label>Carbon Deposits & Emission</label></Col>
        </Col>
        <Col s={12}>
          <Col s={3} className='center'><Button type="button" value="other" name="cause" floating={true} className={(this.state.cause === 'other') ? 'green' : 'blue'} style={radioStyle}/></Col>
          <Col s={9}><label>Company SignUp</label></Col>
        </Col>
    </Col>
  </Col>
</Row>
```